# How to count numbers from a text file in C

Tags: c

So my program is supposed to take input from a file, read each character and put the frequency of characters into an output file. If the character is a number, it should give out the sum of all the numbers (not the digits) in the text.
For example input from the File is "aae 40 20" it should give out sum of the numbers i.e. 60 and so on.
So far I am done with the frequency of every character. It seems that I am not able to figure it out how to give the sum of all numbers as output.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char input_datei[20];
 char alphabet[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
    's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    //Intiaialsie a frequency array, to count the frequency of every alphabet
int frequency[26]={0};
void textAnalysieren(FILE *input,FILE *output,char character,int counter);
int main()
{
    //Requiring a File's name with Length max 20 char long.
    puts("Please give a name for the file to analyse!");
    scanf("%20s",input_datei);

    int counter=0;
    char character;
    FILE *in= fopen(input_datei,"r");
    //If file doesn't exist
    if(in==0){
        printf("Error opening the file\nFile might not exist!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *out=fopen("ausgabe.txt","w");

    textAnalysieren(in,out,character,counter);

    //close the files
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void textAnalysieren(FILE *input,FILE *output,char character,int counter){
     // Loop through every character in the FIle feof return true, when EOF is found
    while((character=fgetc(input)) != EOF){
        // Differentiate between numbers and character's!
        if((character >= 48) && (character <=57)){

                counter =counter+ (character -48);
                if(((character+1) >= 48) && ((character+1) <=57)){
                    counter *=10;
                    counter = counter+((character+1)-48);
                }
               }
        else{
                character= tolower(character);
                for(int s=0;s<26;s++){
                    if(alphabet[s]==character){
                        frequency[s]++;
                    }
                }
    }
}
     //Write to the ausgabe.txt File the Frequency of each character of the alphabet
    for(int s=0;s<26;s++){
        fprintf(output,"Character %c came %d in the text \n",alphabet[s],frequency[s]);
    }
    fprintf(output,"The summ of all your numbers is:  %d \n",counter);
}
```

Comment: `Differentiate between numbers and character's!` - use `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` functions from `ctype.h`. Don't use magic numbers like `48` or `57`, ex.  `character >= '0' && character <= '9'` is clearer. `how to give the sum of all numbers as output` - what do you mean by that? Doesn't the `fprintf(output, .... counter)` print the sum of numbers in the output? What do you want to have in the output? Doesn't the program work as it is now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to programming... and I come up with this dirty code... the code should be self explanatory. Try to compile and run it. I cannot explain very well in English. Basically I make every digit char combination to a string and use atoi() function to make it integer.

```
`
// letters frequency and numbers counter
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 26
#define FILE_NAME_LEN 40

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int letter_pos(char);

    char c;
    int flag = 0; // this is to check the occurence of a digit character
    int sum = 0; // the sum to be stored here, this could be type long
    int lfc[MAX_LEN]; // letter frequency counter array
    char fn[FILE_NAME_LEN]; // file name
    char temp_num[6]; // numeric string, change length but careful of type range. use for storing digit char combinations

    printf("Enter file name to read : "); // prompting the user to enter the text file name to read
    scanf("%s", fn);

    FILE* f_in = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (!f_in) {
        perror(fn);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE* f_out = fopen("afc_out.txt", "w"); // name of the file output
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) lfc[i] = 0; // initializing all elements to zero

    // counting letters frequency and summing all integers
    // changing the code to be efficient could be done here inside the while loop
    while ((c = getc(f_in)) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            ++lfc[letter_pos(c)]; // adding 1 count to this index of lfc array
            if (flag > 0) sum += atoi(temp_num);
            flag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp_num); i++) temp_num[i] = 0;
        }
        //
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            int i = strlen(temp_num);
            if (i == 0) {
                temp_num[0] = c;
                temp_num[1] = '\0';
            }
            else {
                temp_num[i] = c;
                temp_num[i + 1] = '\0';
            }
            ++flag;
        }
        //
        if (!isalnum(c)) {
            if (flag > 0) sum += atoi(temp_num);
            flag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp_num); i++) temp_num[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    // printing out to afc_out.txt file and console
    fprintf(f_out, "\nLetter Frequency Counter\n\"%s\"\n\n", fn);
    printf("\nLetter Frequency Counter\n\"%s\"\n\n", fn);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) {
        fprintf(f_out, "%2c = %2d\n", 'a' + i, lfc[i]);
        printf("%2c = %2d\n", 'a' + i, lfc[i]);
    }  
    fprintf(f_out, "\nSum of Integers : %i\n", sum);
    printf("\nSum of Integers : %i\n", sum);

    fclose(f_in);
    fclose(f_out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int letter_pos(char c) { // returning letter position
    if (isupper(c)) return c - 'A';
    if (islower(c)) return c - 'a';
}
```

`

Note: file to read should be in the same folder with the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

One has two separate requirements:

- Print a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of specific characters of the unaccented latin alphabet, (I assume `a` and `A` are in the same bin.)
- Set up a filter that discards non-numeric input, and sum the numbers of consecutive bytes in base 10.

This is simplified by no numbers not being in the histogram, which allows us to treat the problems separately and concurrently, (in one pass.) For example, this uses [re2c](https://re2c.org/) to simplify lexing, (`'x'` matches case-insensitive.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct Scanner {
    size_t line;
    char *from, *cursor;
    long hist[26];
    long sum;
};

/*!re2c
re2c:yyfill:enable   = 0;
re2c:define:YYCTYPE  = char;
re2c:define:YYCURSOR = s->cursor;
newline = "\n" | ("\r" "\n"?);
dec = [1-9][0-9]*;
end = "\x00";
*/

/** Returns success or failure, on which case `errno` will be set. */
static int lex(struct Scanner *s) {
    assert(s);
scan:
    s->from = s->cursor;
/*!re2c
    * { goto scan; }
    end { return 1; }
    newline { s->line++; goto scan; }
    'a' { s->hist[0]++;  goto scan; }
    'b' { s->hist[1]++;  goto scan; }
    'c' { s->hist[2]++;  goto scan; }
    'd' { s->hist[3]++;  goto scan; }
    'e' { s->hist[4]++;  goto scan; }
    'f' { s->hist[5]++;  goto scan; }
    'g' { s->hist[6]++;  goto scan; }
    'h' { s->hist[7]++;  goto scan; }
    'i' { s->hist[8]++;  goto scan; }
    'j' { s->hist[9]++;  goto scan; }
    'k' { s->hist[10]++; goto scan; }
    'l' { s->hist[11]++; goto scan; }
    'm' { s->hist[12]++; goto scan; }
    'n' { s->hist[13]++; goto scan; }
    'o' { s->hist[14]++; goto scan; }
    'p' { s->hist[15]++; goto scan; }
    'q' { s->hist[16]++; goto scan; }
    'r' { s->hist[17]++; goto scan; }
    's' { s->hist[18]++; goto scan; }
    't' { s->hist[19]++; goto scan; }
    'u' { s->hist[20]++; goto scan; }
    'v' { s->hist[21]++; goto scan; }
    'w' { s->hist[22]++; goto scan; }
    'x' { s->hist[23]++; goto scan; }
    'y' { s->hist[24]++; goto scan; }
    'z' { s->hist[25]++; goto scan; }
    dec {
        long no;
        char *end;
        no = strtol(s->from, &end, 10);
        if(end == s->from || (no == LONG_MAX && errno)) return 0;
        if((s->sum > INT_MAX - no)) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
        s->sum += no;
        goto scan;
    }
*/
}

int main(void) {
    char buffer[256];
    struct Scanner s;
    int success = EXIT_FAILURE;
    size_t i;
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof s); /* `hist` and `sum`. */
    s.line = 1;
    while((s.cursor = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))) {
        size_t len = strlen(s.cursor);
        assert(len > 0);
        if(s.cursor[len - 1] != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Line too long or embedded zeros.\n");
            errno = ERANGE;
            goto catch;
        }
        if(!lex(&s)) goto catch;
    }
    if(ferror(stdin)) goto catch;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof s.hist / sizeof *s.hist; i++)
        if(s.hist[i]) printf("%c: %lu\n", 'a' + i, s.hist[i]);
    printf("sum: %lu\n", s.sum);
    success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    goto finally;
catch:
    assert(!s.from || (s.from < s.cursor && s.from + INT_MAX >= s.cursor));
    fprintf(stderr, "While on line %lu: %.*s.\n", (unsigned long)s.line,
        (int)(s.cursor - s.from), s.from);
    perror("parsing");
finally:
    return success;
}
```

It's very easy to overflow with one's requirements, this will detect it and quit.